# Spark-kafka : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException while writing stream from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming

I am facing an issue while writing the stream on the topic from Spark.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val mySchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("ID", IntegerType),
  StructField("ACCOUNT_NUMBER", StringType)
))

val streamingDataFrame = spark.readStream.schema(mySchema).option("delimiter",",")
                              .csv("file:///opt/files")


streamingDataFrame.selectExpr("CAST(id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
                  .writeStream.format("kafka")
                  .option("topic", "testing")
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "10.55.55.55:9092")
                  .option("checkpointLocation", "file:///opt/")
                  .start().awaitTermination()
```

Error:

```
 2018-09-12 11:09:04,344 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 38 record(s) for testing-0: 30016 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
2018-09-12 11:09:04,358 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver):                                            org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 38 record(s) for testing-0: 30016 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
2018-09-12 11:09:04,359 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
2018-09-12 11:09:04,370 ERROR streaming.StreamExecution: Query [id = 866e4416-138a-42b6-82fd-04b6ee1aa638, runId = 4dd10740-29dd-4275-97e2-a43104d71cf5] terminated with error
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver):   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 38 record(s) for testing-0: 30016 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
```

My sbt details:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.0"
```

But when I send message through server using `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh` and `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh`  I can send and receive message

Comment: Matthias J. Sax, did you solve this issue? Is it possible that you need to upgrade the kafka-client version to 1.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the value of `request.timeout.ms` on the client side.

Kafka groups records into batches in order to increase throughput. When a new record is added into the batch, it must be sent within the time limit. `request.timeout.ms` is a configurable parameter (default value is 30sec) that controls this time limit.

When a batch is queued for longer period, the a `TimeoutException` is being thrown and records will be removed from the queue (and therefore messages will not be delivered).

Comment: Need to add this parameter in client side or kafka server configuration

Comment: @aravinth on the client side.